# Why does React component update if props and state didn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

A React Copmponent is rendering when its state or propr remain the same. I don't get why it does it rerender/update since the result wouldn't change

```
class A extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Hello")
    return "Foo";
  }
}
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { a: "ASDA" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={()=>this.setState({a: Math.random()}) }>asdsa</button>
        <div>{this.state.a}</div>
        <A />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Whenever I click the button, component A is rerendered (I can see "hello" in the console)
I thought React was avoiding many useless rerenderings.

Comment: Children will rerender if parent rerenders, which happens on button click

Comment: So your question is ... you thought React was avoiding many useless re-renderings?  Do you have a specific coding problem you are trying to solve?   You called setState() in the parent component which causes the parent and all child components to re-render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your parent component is re-rendering because its state changes.

When a component re-renders, all its children are re-rendered. This means that the render function runs, and the result is added to the virtual DOM.

This result is then compared with the existing DOM. It doesn't mean that that actual DOM changes for the child components, just that they are re-evaluated because the DOM *might* need to change.

If it turns out that the child element *does* need to change, then that element in the actual DOM is re-rendered. If the child element doesn't need to change, that element in the DOM remains un-effected.

**This is generally fine and has minimal to no performance impacts for small components, so usually you don't need to worry about it.**

If you have deep component hierarchies or components with complex render functions that perform computationally expensive operations, consider using `React.memo` if you feel that the render cycle is causing a hit on performance.